# How to control the font size of quoted text in Markdown

Tags: r, markdown

The font of quoted text on Markdown is often too large in contrast to the rest of the (unquoted) text. This is an example:
[image]

generated with RStudio as

```
#####Intution:

> **[Identification of an MA model is often best done with the ACF rather
> than the PACF]((https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat510/node/62))**.
> 
> For an MA model, the theoretical PACF does not shut off, but instead
> tapers toward 0 in some manner.  A clearer pattern for an MA model is
> in the ACF.  The ACF will have non-zero autocorrelations only at lags
> involved in the model.
> 
> A moving average term in a time series model is a past error (multiplied by a coefficient).

The $q^{\text{th}}$-order moving average model, denoted by MA(q) is
```

Comment: you'll probably have to do something with the underlying CSS (perhaps you can override the definition of this `<div>` element with appropriate CSS directives in your markdown file).  I'm not an expert at that, so I hope someone who is comes along.

Comment: @Ben Bolker Thank you. It seems as though it did happen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This seems to be part of RMarkdown's default CSS for html output, where blockquotes have:

```
blockquote {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 17.5px;
    border-left: 5px solid #eee;
}
```

You can override this by creating a custom CSS file e.g. `custom.css`:

```
blockquote {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 5px solid #eee;
}
```

And then adding it to the header of your RMarkdown doc:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Me"
output: 
  html_document:
    css: custom.css
---
```

Comment: I understand what CSS does, but I have no experience with it. I use the `knit` function in RStudio to compile the html file before uploading to GitHub. I have no clue where I could possibly keep the CSS file you wrote.

Comment: Just in the same folder as your RMarkdown file. R will look there when you give a relative path like `custom.css` in the header.

Comment: You could also insert `css` code block : \```{css}....\```

Answer (score 8):

As an alternative to external css file you could use css code chunk:

````
---
title: "Example"
date: "`r Sys.time()`"
output: html_document
---

```{css style settings, echo = FALSE}
blockquote {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    border-left: 5px solid #eee;
}
```

Now quotes will be as you wish

> example quote (blah blah blah)
````